# Redux DevTools now showing typescript Map object in State view

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-devtools-extension

We just migrated from immutable to immer and got a surprise when using the Redux Devtool in chrome (same in firefox)

Our redux state uses typscript maps, sets and arrays. For example

```
export interface IStoreRoot {
    appDefinition: IStoreAppDef;
    discussions: IStoreDiscussions;
    themes: IStoreThemes;
    ns: Map<nsUid, INameSpace>;
...
}
```

When checking in de ReduxDev Tools the ns is always empty even though it has values inside. The same think for other typescript objects. Plain objects are fine.

Did somebody encounter the same issue ?

Comment: There is an open [issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/496) for this

Answer (score 3):

Just for those using NgRx there is also something similar in order to be able to see the actual data of a Map object in state view:

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
    maxAge: 25,
    logOnly: environment.production,
    serialize: {
      options: {
        map: true,
      },
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Was facing this issue.

Going through the [docs](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#serialize), it seems that serializing Maps(and few other objects/data structures) are not enabled by default.

You need to add code explicitly to serialize them. For example in this case:

```
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer,
 window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
 window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__({
  serialize: { 
    options: {
     map: true,
    }
  }
}));
```